# mpirun command showing strange behaviour in bash

Tags: bash, openmpi

I have a quick question.

I was recently trying to run an mpi program using my school's server and I run into the following 'weird' problem:

In order to execute the 'mpirun' command I had to place its path into my default path in .bashrc which I did and then typed:

```
mpirun -n 16 ./myprogram
```

only to get an error about a missing library called: libmpi.so.0

However if I tried to run a program using the full mpirun path like below

```
/usr/lib64/openmpi/bin/mpirun -n 16 ./myprogram
```

all was good.

I checked openmpi's FAQ and it said that I needed to put the following line into my .bashrc

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/openmpi/lib
```

which actually fixed things for me but my question still remains unresolved:

Why was that happening?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Because Open MPI's wrapper compilers don't automatically -rpath the location of where libmpi.so is located when compiling / linking myprogram (we take a minimalist approach in the flags that are passed in the OMPI wrapper compilers -- if they're not *needed*, we don't put them there).

Specifically, when you run an executable in Linux, the run-time linker will look to find all the libraries that are needed for that executable (run "ldd myprogram" and you'll see a list of the libraries that are needed for myprogram).  It'll look in all the system default locations (which are, themselves, configurable by the sysadmins).  It'll also look in all the directories specified by LD_LIBRARY_PATH -- LD_LIBRARY_PATH is effectively a per-user method of extending the list of directories for the linker to search to find shared libraries.

I'm guessing that libmpi.so is not in any of the system default locations, and therefore you need to specify its directory in LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Alternatively, you could add an -rpath clause when you link myprogram.  For example:

```
mpicc myprogram.c -o myprogram -Wl,-rpath /opt/openmpi/lib
```

This would embed the location /opt/openmpi/lib to the myprogram binary itself, and the linker will also look in that location for libmpi.so (and any other libraries that need to be resolved).  For example:

```
# Without an rpath clause:
[8:45] svbu-mpi:~/mpi % mpicc hello.c -o hello
[8:45] svbu-mpi:~/mpi % ldd hello
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff7ffe000)
libmpi.so.0 => not found
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003d58c00000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003d59c00000)
libnuma.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libnuma.so.1 (0x00007ffff7ddf000)
libpci.so.3 => /lib64/libpci.so.3 (0x00007ffff7bd2000)
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x0000003d5a000000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x0000003d5c000000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x0000003d5a800000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003d59400000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003d59000000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003d58800000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x0000003d5b000000)
```

Notice the "not found" in the libmpi.so entry.

You could set LD_LIBRARY_PATH and have it found:

```
[8:45] svbu-mpi:~/mpi % setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /home/jsquyres/bogus/lib
[8:45] svbu-mpi:~/mpi % ldd hello
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff7ffe000)
libmpi.so.0 => /home/jsquyres/bogus/lib/libmpi.so.0 (0x00007ffff7b06000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003d58c00000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003d59c00000)
libnuma.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libnuma.so.1 (0x00007ffff78e8000)
libpci.so.3 => /lib64/libpci.so.3 (0x00007ffff76db000)
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x0000003d5a000000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x0000003d5c000000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x0000003d5a800000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003d59400000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003d59000000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003d58800000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x0000003d5b000000)
```

Or you could use an -rpath clause (and then the setting in LD_LIBRARY_PATH becomes irrelevant):

```
[8:45] svbu-mpi:~/mpi % mpicc hello.c -o hello -Wl,-rpath /home/jsquyres/bogus/lib
[8:45] svbu-mpi:~/mpi % ldd hello
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff7ffe000)
libmpi.so.0 => /home/jsquyres/bogus/lib/libmpi.so.0 (0x00007ffff7b06000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003d58c00000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003d59c00000)
libnuma.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libnuma.so.1 (0x00007ffff78e8000)
libpci.so.3 => /lib64/libpci.so.3 (0x00007ffff76db000)
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x0000003d5a000000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x0000003d5c000000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x0000003d5a800000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003d59400000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003d59000000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003d58800000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x0000003d5b000000)
```

Comment: So..if the problem is with the library path as you suggest, then what exactly changes if I run mpirun giving its full path? In other words, what happens in that case and the library is read?

Comment: (somehow SO is not mailing me when new comments are added; sorry for the delay) When you provide the full path to mpirun, it automatically sets LD_LIBRARY_PATH for you on remote nodes, meaning that it isn't relying on your .bashrc to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  See the man page for mpirun.1 for more information.

Comment: Makes much more sense now. But then: Why LD_LIBRARY_PATH is automatically set when I provide the full path but when I don't I have to manually specify it? Is that related to the mpirun command or is it bash-related? Thanks again.